# Rails - Coffee Script Source gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I started working with Ruby on Rails v4.2.5 a couple months back and I started getting an ExecJS error saying "TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method" at this line in my code:

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

After searching a solution I found was to use Coffee-Script-Source version 1.8.0 rather than the 1.10.0 and all my problems using JavaScript disappeared. Just to make sure this was really a problem I ended up changing it to the latest version(version 1.10.0) again by not specifying a version and the error messages showed up again and went away after specifying the older one.

My question is, why having a newer version is causing errors and a previous version working for my project(s)? Also are others are running into the same errors?

Comment: That might be important: have you restart your application after each change in your Gemfile?

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes, I always kill the locally running server and then restart it afterwards. I use one terminal so I have to kill the webbricks server to run bundle